# Identify varying rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    
a       0        1     
b       3        3     
c       1        1
a       0        1
a       1        2
b       3        3
```

I need to identify every row which has different values while filtering based on a value in a column. Example : when I filter the dataframe with value 'a' in ColA, the 5th row has different values in the ColB and ColC.

I tried with

df['result']=df['ColA'].ne(df['ColA'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)

which resulted in:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| b | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| b | 3 | 3 | 1 |

What I need is(Filtering for the value 'a' should identify the row with different values in other columns):

| ColA | ColB | ColC | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| b | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| b | 3 | 3 | 1 |

If I use groupby method:

df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())['ColA'].nunique()

it works only with small dataframes with a few data types.

Comment: Why can't you just do `df['result'] = df['ColB'] == df['ColC']`?

I didn't understand what do you mean by filtering by ColA here.

Comment: why the result column is 1 for the row b, 3, 3? of what I understand, it should be 0 as it is the first row with b in ColA?

Comment: @MayurKr.Garg Here, the values in a single row should be considered together. So, should be comparing the changes happening in the rows. Example : 4th row has same values like in the 1st row. But 5th row has different values and hence the value 1 in result column.

Comment: @Ben.T You are correct. That's a mistake from my end.

Comment: Why is the result in the first row 0 and in the third row 1?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can `drop_duplicates` and then create the result column with `groupby` and `cumcount` to get an identifier per unique row per group.

```
print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ColA','ColB','ColC'])
        .assign(result=lambda x: x.groupby('ColA').cumcount()))
#   ColA  ColB  ColC  result
# 0    a     0     1       0
# 1    b     3     3       0
# 2    c     1     1       0
# 4    a     1     2       1
```

As you can see, you are "missing rows" from the original df, so `merge` it back to df.

```
df = (
    df.merge(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ColA','ColB','ColC'])
               .assign(result=lambda x: x.groupby('ColA').cumcount()), 
             how='left')
)
print(df)
#   ColA  ColB  ColC  result
# 0    a     0     1       0
# 1    b     3     3       0
# 2    c     1     1       0
# 3    a     0     1       0
# 4    a     1     2       1
# 5    b     3     3       0
```

Comment: Why `(c 1 1)` is 0 and not 1? (The question is not clear for me...)

Comment: @Corralien I understand as they want to create a identifier per group ColA per unique row (ColB-ColC), so `c 1 1` being the first row with c in ColA, it gives 0. I can see why you came up with your answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have an unique id, use `pd.factorize` on your entire dataframe without `groupby`:

```
df['result'] = pd.factorize(df.agg(tuple, axis=1))[0]
print(df)

# Output
  ColA  ColB  ColC  result
0    a     0     1       0
1    b     3     3       1
2    c     1     1       2
3    a     0     1       0
4    a     1     2       3
5    b     3     3       1
```

---

You can use `duplicated`:

```
df['result'] = (~df.duplicated(keep=False)).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
  ColA  ColB  ColC  result
0    a     0     1       0
1    b     3     3       0
2    c     1     1       1
3    a     0     1       0
4    a     1     2       1
5    b     3     3       0
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is removing duplicated rows by `drop_duplicates(keep=False)` and creating `result` columns based on indexes.

```
data = {
    'ColA': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 
    'ColB': [0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3],
    'ColC': [1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

unique_rows = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df['result'] = df.index.isin(unique_rows.index).astype(int)

print(df)
```